# removing files using git-filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I have a huge repo and I want to shrink it. A `git-filter-repo --analyze` shows that I had commited loads of tiffs (by mistake, directory doesnt exist anymore) and I would like to remove all these from my history and shrink the size of my .git file.

The top3 in my `directories-all-sizes.txt` is:

```
=== All directories by reverse size ===
Format: unpacked size, packed size, date deleted, directory name
  10427033696 2301950509 <present>  <toplevel>
  4835103008  917677623 <present>  data
  4398972219  825347243 2020-12-29 data/fov
  3972526203  745309155 2020-05-20 fov
```

and `extensions-all-sizes.txt`

```
=== All extensions by reverse size ===
Format: unpacked size, packed size, date deleted, extension name
  2464104104 1412058140 2020-12-29 .tif
   278175984  272096000 <present>  .gif
  1249866460  269140539 <present>  .json
  5991626887  172076504 <present>  .csv
   215493375   71506246 <present>  .tsv
```

I would like to remove the folder `data/fov` (this is where the tifs are) and most (but not all) of my gif, json, csv, tsv files.

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/https://).

For example, I was removing some committed large files from the repository:

```bash
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M
```

But there are more examples in the documentation.